# Webpack watch config in development mode not copying css files using boilerplate created by create react app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-extension, webpack-watch

I am developing chrome extension with react using create react app v3 boilerplate. I am using inject page strategy using content scripts. I am not using webpack dev server instead I had a watch script that watch changes and copy the updated files in build directory. Also I integrate Chrome [**webpack-chrome-extension-reloader**](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/hot-reloading-extensions-using-webpack-cdfa0e4d5a08) plugin which is working fine. Problem is that it is not picking up css files and not copying it.

**Here is my watch script**

```
// Do this as the first thing so that any code reading it knows the right env.
process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'development';
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

const fs = require('fs-extra');
const paths = require('../config/paths');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const configFactory = require('../config/webpack.config');
const config = configFactory('development');

// removes react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js at first in the array
config.entry.app = config.entry.app.filter(
  entry => !entry.includes('webpackHotDevClient')
);

config.output.path = paths.appBuild;
paths.publicUrl = paths.appBuild + '/';

webpack(config).watch({}, (err, stats) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    copyPublicFolder();
  }
  console.error(
    stats.toString({
      chunks: false,
      colors: true
    })
  );
});

function copyPublicFolder() {
  fs.copySync(paths.appPublic, paths.appBuild, {
    dereference: true,
    filter: file => file !== paths.appHtml
  });
}
```

**Here is my webpack.config.js**

```
 .....
 .....

// This is the production and development configuration.
// It is focused on developer experience, fast rebuilds, and a minimal bundle.
module.exports = function(webpackEnv) {
  const isEnvDevelopment = webpackEnv === 'development';
  const isEnvProduction = webpackEnv === 'production';

  // Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
  // It requires a trailing slash, or the file assets will get an incorrect path.
  // In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
  const publicPath = isEnvProduction
    ? paths.servedPath
    : isEnvDevelopment && '/';
  // Some apps do not use client-side routing with pushState.
  // For these, "homepage" can be set to "." to enable relative asset paths.
  const shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths = publicPath === './';

  // `publicUrl` is just like `publicPath`, but we will provide it to our app
  // as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
  // Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_URL%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_URL%xyz.
  const publicUrl = isEnvProduction
    ? publicPath.slice(0, -1)
    : isEnvDevelopment && '';
  // Get environment variables to inject into our app.
  const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

  // common function to get style loaders
  const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
    const loaders = [
      isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve('style-loader'),
      isEnvProduction && {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        options: Object.assign(
          {},
          shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths ? { publicPath: '../../' } : undefined
        )
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        options: cssOptions
      },
      {
        // Options for PostCSS as we reference these options twice
        // Adds vendor prefixing based on your specified browser support in
        // package.json
        loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
        options: {
          // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
          // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2677
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: () => [
            require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
            require('postcss-preset-env')({
              autoprefixer: {
                flexbox: 'no-2009'
              },
              stage: 3
            }),
            // Adds PostCSS Normalize as the reset css with default options,
            // so that it honors browserslist config in package.json
            // which in turn let's users customize the target behavior as per their needs.
            postcssNormalize()
          ],
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap
        }
      }
    ].filter(Boolean);
    if (preProcessor) {
      loaders.push({
        loader: require.resolve(preProcessor),
        options: {
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap
        }
      });
    }
    return loaders;
  };

  return {
    mode: isEnvProduction ? 'production' : isEnvDevelopment && 'development',
    // Stop compilation early in production
    bail: isEnvProduction,
    devtool: isEnvProduction
      ? shouldUseSourceMap
        ? 'source-map'
        : false
      : isEnvDevelopment && 'cheap-module-source-map',
    // These are the "entry points" to our application.
    // This means they will be the "root" imports that are included in JS bundle.
    entry: {
      app: [
        // Include an alternative client for WebpackDevServer. A client's job is to
        // connect to WebpackDevServer by a socket and get notified about changes.
        // When you save a file, the client will either apply hot updates (in case
        // of CSS changes), or refresh the page (in case of JS changes). When you
        // make a syntax error, this client will display a syntax error overlay.
        // Note: instead of the default WebpackDevServer client, we use a custom one
        // to bring better experience for Create React App users. You can replace
        // the line below with these two lines if you prefer the stock client:
        // require.resolve('webpack-dev-server/client') + '?/',
        // require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'),
        isEnvDevelopment &&
          require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
        // Finally, this is your app's code:
        paths.appIndexJs
        // We include the app code last so that if there is a runtime error during
        // initialization, it doesn't blow up the WebpackDevServer client, and
        // changing JS code would still trigger a refresh.
      ].filter(Boolean),
      background: paths.appBackgroundJS,
      content: paths.appContentJs
    },
    output: {
      // The build folder.
      path: isEnvProduction ? paths.appBuild : undefined,

      // Add /* filename */ comments to generated require()s in the output.
      pathinfo: isEnvDevelopment,

      // There will be one main bundle, and one file per asynchronous chunk.
      // In development, it does not produce real files.
      filename: chunkData => {
        if (chunkData.chunk.name === 'app')
          return isEnvProduction
            ? 'static/js/[name].js'
            : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/bundle.js';
        return `static/js/[name].js`;
      },

      // TODO: remove this when upgrading to webpack 5
      futureEmitAssets: true,

      // We inferred the "public path" (such as / or /my-project) from homepage.
      // We use "/" in development.
      publicPath: publicPath,

      // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
      devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: isEnvProduction
        ? info =>
            path
              .relative(paths.appSrc, info.absoluteResourcePath)
              .replace(/\\/g, '/')
        : isEnvDevelopment &&
          (info => path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/'))
    },
    optimization: {
      minimize: isEnvProduction,
      minimizer: [
        // This is only used in production mode
        new TerserPlugin({
          terserOptions: {
            parse: {
              // we want terser to parse ecma 8 code. However, we don't want it
              // to apply any minfication steps that turns valid ecma 5 code
              // into invalid ecma 5 code. This is why the 'compress' and 'output'
              // sections only apply transformations that are ecma 5 safe
              // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/4234
              ecma: 8
            },
            compress: {
              ecma: 5,
              warnings: false,
              // Disabled because of an issue with Uglify breaking seemingly valid code:
              // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2376
              // Pending further investigation:
              // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/2011
              comparisons: false,
              // Disabled because of an issue with Terser breaking valid code:
              // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5250
              // Pending futher investigation:
              // https://github.com/terser-js/terser/issues/120
              inline: 2
            },
            mangle: {
              safari10: true
            },
            output: {
              ecma: 5,
              comments: false,
              // Turned on because emoji and regex is not minified properly using default
              // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2488
              ascii_only: true
            }
          },
          // Use multi-process parallel running to improve the build speed
          // Default number of concurrent runs: os.cpus().length - 1
          // Disabled on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) due to an issue with Terser
          // https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin/issues/21
          parallel: !isWsl,
          // Enable file caching
          cache: true,
          sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap
        }),
        // This is only used in production mode
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
          cssProcessorOptions: {
            parser: safePostCssParser,
            map: shouldUseSourceMap
              ? {
                  // `inline: false` forces the sourcemap to be output into a
                  // separate file
                  inline: false,
                  // `annotation: true` appends the sourceMappingURL to the end of
                  // the css file, helping the browser find the sourcemap
                  annotation: true
                }
              : false
          }
        })
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
      // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
      // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/253
      modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
        modules.additionalModulePaths || []
      ),
      // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
      // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
      // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/290
      // `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
      // for React Native Web.
      extensions: paths.moduleFileExtensions
        .map(ext => `.${ext}`)
        .filter(ext => useTypeScript || !ext.includes('ts')),
      alias: {
        // Support React Native Web
        // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
        'react-native': 'react-native-web'
      },
      plugins: [
        // Adds support for installing with Plug'n'Play, leading to faster installs and adding
        // guards against forgotten dependencies and such.
        PnpWebpackPlugin,
        // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
        // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
        // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
        // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
        // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
        new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson])
      ]
    },
    resolveLoader: {
      plugins: [
        // Also related to Plug'n'Play, but this time it tells Webpack to load its loaders
        // from the current package.
        PnpWebpackPlugin.moduleLoader(module)
      ]
    },
    module: {
      strictExportPresence: true,
      rules: [
        // Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
        { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

        // First, run the linter.
        // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
        {
          test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
          enforce: 'pre',
          use: [
            {
              options: {
                formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
                eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint')
              },
              loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader')
            }
          ],
          include: paths.appSrc
        },
        {
          // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
          // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
          // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
          oneOf: [
            // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
            // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
            // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
            {
              test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
              loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
              options: {
                limit: 10000,
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
              }
            },
            // Process application JS with Babel.
            // The preset includes JSX, Flow, TypeScript, and some ESnext features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
              include: paths.appSrc,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                customize: require.resolve(
                  'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'
                ),

                plugins: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-plugin-named-asset-import'),
                    {
                      loaderMap: {
                        svg: {
                          ReactComponent: '@svgr/webpack?-svgo,+ref![path]'
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                ],
                // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
                // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
                // directory for faster rebuilds.
                cacheDirectory: true,
                cacheCompression: isEnvProduction,
                compact: isEnvProduction
              }
            },
            // Process any JS outside of the app with Babel.
            // Unlike the application JS, we only compile the standard ES features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
              exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
                compact: false,
                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
                    { helpers: true }
                  ]
                ],
                cacheDirectory: true,
                cacheCompression: isEnvProduction,

                // If an error happens in a package, it's possible to be
                // because it was compiled. Thus, we don't want the browser
                // debugger to show the original code. Instead, the code
                // being evaluated would be much more helpful.
                sourceMaps: false
              }
            },
            // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
            // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
            // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
            // In production, we use MiniCSSExtractPlugin to extract that CSS
            // to a file, but in development "style" loader enables hot editing
            // of CSS.
            // By default we support CSS Modules with the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap
              }),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
            // using the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                modules: true,
                getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent
              })
            },
            // Opt-in support for SASS (using .scss or .sass extensions).
            // By default we support SASS Modules with the
            // extensions .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassRegex,
              exclude: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 2,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules, but using SASS
            // using the extension .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 2,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                  modules: true,
                  getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent
                },
                'sass-loader'
              )
            },
            // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
            // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
            // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
            // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
            // that fall through the other loaders.
            {
              loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
              // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
              // its runtime that would otherwise be processed through "file" loader.
              // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
              // by webpacks internal loaders.
              exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
              options: {
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
              }
            }
            // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
            // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      isEnvDevelopment &&
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
          verbose: true,
          cleanStaleWebpackAssets: true,
          cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: [
            '*.hot-update.json',
            '*.hot-update.js',
            '*.hot-update.js.map'
          ]
        }),
      // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
        Object.assign(
          {},
          {
            inject: true,
            chunks: ['app'],
            template: paths.appHtml,
            filename: 'index.html',
          },
          isEnvProduction
            ? {
                minify: {
                  removeComments: true,
                  collapseWhitespace: true,
                  removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                  useShortDoctype: true,
                  removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                  removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                  keepClosingSlash: true,
                  minifyJS: true,
                  minifyCSS: true,
                  minifyURLs: true
                }
              }
            : undefined
        )
      ),

      // Makes some environment variables available in index.html.
      // The public URL is available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
      // <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
      // In production, it will be an empty string unless you specify "homepage"
      // in `package.json`, in which case it will be the pathname of that URL.
      // In development, this will be an empty string.
      new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw),
      // This gives some necessary context to module not found errors, such as
      // the requesting resource.
      new ModuleNotFoundPlugin(paths.appPath),
      // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
      // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
      // It is absolutely essential that NODE_ENV is set to production
      // during a production build.
      // Otherwise React will be compiled in the very slow development mode.
      new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
      // This is necessary to emit hot updates (currently CSS only):
      isEnvDevelopment && new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      // Watcher doesn't work well if you mistype casing in a path so we use
      // a plugin that prints an error when you attempt to do this.
      // See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/240
      isEnvDevelopment && new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),

      // If you require a missing module and then `npm install` it, you still have
      // to restart the development server for Webpack to discover it. This plugin
      // makes the discovery automatic so you don't have to restart.
      // See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/186
      isEnvDevelopment &&
        new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
      isEnvProduction &&
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
          // both options are optional
          filename: 'static/css/[name].css',
          chunkFilename: 'static/css/[name].css'
        }),

      // Generate a manifest file which contains a mapping of all asset filenames
      // to their corresponding output file so that tools can pick it up without
      // having to parse `index.html`.
      new ManifestPlugin({
        fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
        publicPath: publicPath,
        generate: (seed, files) => {
          const manifestFiles = files.reduce(function(manifest, file) {
            manifest[file.name] = file.path;
            return manifest;
          }, seed);

          return {
            files: manifestFiles
          };
        }
      }),
      // Moment.js is an extremely popular library that bundles large locale files
      // by default due to how Webpack interprets its code. This is a practical
      // solution that requires the user to opt into importing specific locales.
      // https://github.com/jmblog/how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack
      // You can remove this if you don't use Moment.js:
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
      // Generate a service worker script that will precache, and keep up to date,
      // the HTML & assets that are part of the Webpack build.
      isEnvProduction &&
        new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.GenerateSW({
          clientsClaim: true,
          exclude: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/],
          importWorkboxFrom: 'cdn',
          navigateFallback: publicUrl + '/index.html',
          navigateFallbackBlacklist: [
            // Exclude URLs starting with /_, as they're likely an API call
            new RegExp('^/_'),
            // Exclude URLs containing a dot, as they're likely a resource in
            // public/ and not a SPA route
            new RegExp('/[^/]+\\.[^/]+$')
          ]
        }),

      // Chrome extension hot reloading.
      isEnvDevelopment &&
        new ChromeExtensionReloader({
          reloadPage: false, // Force the reload of the page also
          // entries: {
          //   // The entries used for the content/background scripts
          //   contentScript: 'content',
          //   background: 'background' // *REQUIRED
          // }
        })
    ].filter(Boolean),
    // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
    // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
    node: {
      module: 'empty',
      dgram: 'empty',
      dns: 'mock',
      fs: 'empty',
      http2: 'empty',
      net: 'empty',
      tls: 'empty',
      child_process: 'empty'
    },
    // Turn off performance processing because we utilize
    // our own hints via the FileSizeReporter
    performance: false
  };
};
```

**The folder structure which I had after build is this**

[image]

**But when I ran npm run watch css files not picked up**

[image]

**Here is the watch summary returned.**

[image]

Need help to copy css files to build folder so that my hot reload can work correctly.

Thanks